# Check where the consumer of kafka are connected

Tags: apache-kafka

**Scenario** 
We have a shared Kafka environment and it is being used by multiple machines.
We manage by collaborating and run only one application at one time. 
But now 1 consumer is running and there is no machine (in our knowledge) that is now running that application. Due to this, we are not able to properly test the application flow.

**Question**
Is there a way in Kafka (or Kafka Confluent) to tell on which machine(IP Address) is the consumer is running? So that I can identify the machine and kill the process there.

Answer (score 0):

You can use any approach

- `kafka-consumer-group API`

  Command to run in bash is:

  ```bash
  ./kafka-consumer-groups.sh --describe  --group=<my-group> \ 
    --bootstrap-server=<hostname>:<port> --members
  ```

  Output of above command will give you these details.

  | CONSUMER-ID | HOST | CLIENT-ID | #PARTITIONS |
  | --- | --- | --- | --- |
- `Zookeeper`

  You can store instance ip in zookeeper using curator when starting consumer and remove the entry while stopping the instance.
- `Kafka Manager`

  There are some third party tools which give us kafka related metrics like

  - Brokers List
  - Topic List
  - Consumer List
  - Lags

Note: Approach 1 and 3 will give you correct answer after some delay